# Escape space parameters on Slim Framework

Tags: slim

```
 $app->get('/login/{email}_{appkey}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        //CODE
    });
```

This is a very simple code, i want to pass the Email and an App Key. The problem is that sometimes the appkey can have a **_** character. Is there any way to escape this or should i change this to /email/appkey?

My other question is about passwords, since they can accept almost anything (unless told otherwise) what if the user create a password with the space character? How to deal with this?

Comment: You should not pass an email address in a uri path as parameter. This wont work and is a security issue. Instead you should post the login data via a POST payload.

Comment: Although everything is on a HTTPS environment i switched to POST, easier since i don't need to deal with escaping. Thanks.